# Is there a shuttle bus from Maastricht airport to Maastricht?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, maastricht, mst

I was looking for connections to the Maastricht airport. Apparently there is a shuttle but I don't find either time tables or prices. I only found to Achen.

Anyone knows if such service exists?
Is the airport served by other regular bus services (excluding dedicated services like a shuttle)? What is the cost?

Answer (score 6):

On the [VVV Maastricht](http://www.vvvmaastricht.nl/transport/airport.html) website (VVV=Tourist Info), I see that there is a shuttle service, but also a regular bus.

The regular bus is operated by [Veolia](http://www.veolia-transport.nl), where you need line 159, which connects the airport with Maastricht Central Station. It is an [hourly](http://timetables.vtnl.net/Timetable.aspx?q=cG9pbnRJZD0yOTg5MDMmbGluZUlkPTUwODAmZGlyZWN0aW9uSWQ9MSZhcmVhSWQ9NzA=) service, leaving the airport at 04 every hour. The footnote is important, as it is only operated in vacation periods. Vacation periods are official holidays, which you can find on [their calendar](http://www.veolia-transport.nl/limburg/reisinformatie/regionale-reisinformatie/vakantie-en-feestdagen/index.html) (first table!). I think you can understand the second column

The [shuttle bus](http://www.maa.nl/en-us/passengers/preparations/access/airportxpress), I could find, is indeed mentioning Aachen, but not Maastricht.

Comment: I know Veolia no longer operates in Maastricht and some schedules have changed. Do you know if the information is still up to date?

Comment: @nsn It seems like most of the links are broken by now. Feel free to update or post a new answer.

Answer (score 5):

After calling the airport I got the following information:

There is usually a bus every half an hour from the aiport (during day time). At night and weekends it's usually every hour.
It's a regular bus and it's possible to buy a ticket at the airport for 4€.

Since it's a regular bus information (timetables) can be found at [www.9292.nl](http://www.9292.nl/)

Meanwhile I discovered that there is [this shuttle bus that serves the airport (click for more information)](http://www.voyages-lelan.be/xml/navette-aeroport-charleroi.html?LANG=fr&IDC=71). It doesn't run very often though.